# count query is not giving me the result I expect

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find out the quantity of products sold each year, I have 1000 records in my database, the problem I am encountering is that when I run my query all the years are adding up to 1000, so my result is saying that I have sold 1000 products per year. although, this is not the case. any help would be mostly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE product_dim(
    product_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    product_name    VARCHAR(25),
    quantity    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT  pk_product_dim PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
);


CREATE TABLE time_dim(
    time_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    year    INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT  pk_time_dim PRIMARY KEY (time_id)
);

Select    year ,count(*) product_id
FROM      product_dim, time_dim
INNER JOIN store_dim
ON account_dim.account_id=store_dim.fk1_account_id 
   group by year
```

Comment: Your query simply makes no sense.  `count(*)` as `product_id`?  No `join` conditions?

Comment: What is logical relation between table product_dim and table time_dim?

Comment: year is in time dim and my store dim

Comment: Add some sample data (*formatted* text please, no screenshots) and the expected output based on that data.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return 1000,because you are using **COUNT(*)**. It will count total number of rows on that row. You need to use **SUM(column_name)**.
Refer this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp

and what is the relation between **product_dim** & **time_dim**

Comment: when I change it to sum it gives me a really high number because its just adding the ids up, i am using product dim because I want to find out the total number of products sold each year

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to count the number of products, you have to add the junction to the "product_dim":

```
SELECT year
    ,sum(c.quantity) AS quantity
FROM time_dim a
INNER JOIN store_dim b
    ON a.time_id = b.time_id
INNER JOIN product_dim c
    ON b.product_id = c.product_id
GROUP BY year
```